# including customized header files in c

Tags: c, header-files

I am simply trying to implement my own header file in C.
 First up, I have a file INC2.h

```
void diffadd(int b[], int n);
int diffcheck(int m);
```

Then I make a file INC2.cpp

```
void diffadd(int b[], int n)
     {
     int i=0;
     for (i=0; i < n; i++)
          {
          b[i]=b[i]+1;
          printf("\n%d",b[i])
           }
      }
 int diffcheck(int m)
     {
      return (m*5);
      }
```

Then in the main file LETS.cpp

```
  #include"inc2.h" 
  void main()
      {
       clrscr();
       int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
       diffadd(a,5);
       int t=diffcheck(5);
       printf("t=%d",t);
       getch();
       }
```

Now I compile inc2.cpp.   FINE!

Then I compile lets.cpp.

I get the following errors:

Undefined symbol diffcheck(int) in module LETS.cpp

Undefined symbol diffadd(int near*, int) in module LETS.cpp

Interestingly, if I include inc2.cpp in LETS.cpp, IT WORKS.

If I create a separate header file HEAD.h and define all the functions here, IT WORKS.

PLease Explain what is happening here!

Comment: What do you mean by "Then I compile inc2.h. FINE!"? Do you compile a precompiled header?

Comment: Urgh. Is that really what your code looks like or is it due to the paste into StackOverflow? :x

Comment: Please include the exact command line you use to invoke the compiler.

Comment: @Zeta- I have used the Turbo C compiler here.

Comment: Better to write steps/commands of compilation too.

Answer (score 3):

You should look up some tutorials on the internet about *program linking*.

When you compile a single `.c/.cpp` file, compilers often do linking work for you and you have a complete executable on its output. But when you have more than one source file, things get complicated: each of the source files (not `.h`, headers!) is compiled to an intermediate file, *object file*, which contains a list of *symbols* (function/variables names/addresses in memory - all that resides in memory and is visible to external files) that the file provides and a separate list of symbols that the file requires. This stage is called `compilation` itself. Then you have a bunch of object files that can be combined with a special program, *linker*, into the executable you want - this is called `linking` a program. The linker gets the lists of required/provided symbols of all files and looks up whether all required symbols can be found in the given set of provided symbols in all object files and then *links* provided functions to places where they're required.

Header files are just text stubs that are included literally into source files (.c/.cpp), they're not a subject for compilation (with some exceptions).

Thus: compile your `inc2.cpp` into an object file, compile `lets.cpp` into another object file and then let the linker combine them into the executable.

Comment: I have in the TURBOC3/SOURCE folder, the object files of LETS and INC2 modules. What more do I do?

Comment: @Peps it depends on your compiler. I don't have TurboC available now, so I can't help with the compiler options and such (I've just tried to explain the essence of the C way of making executables). Please read manual to the compiler, search the internet for TurboC tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

When First time I define my own header file I also got the same error. Then I define a header file with definition of function and that worked for me.

You just need to do is. Define header file like

```
//inc2.h
void diffadd(int b[], int n)
 {
 int i=0;
 for (i=0; i < n; i++)
      {
      b[i]=b[i]+1;
      printf("\n%d",b[i])
       }
  }
```

int diffcheck(int m)
     {
      return (m*5);
      }

After that call the funciton in main file like

```
//Lets.cpp
#include"inc2.h" 
void main()
  {
   clrscr();
   int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
   diffadd(a,5);
   int t=diffcheck(5);
   printf("t=%d",t);
   getch();
   }
```

It might work for you too.

Either you can also write your header file like name
     #include"inc2.pp"
That will also work.

Comment: I already have mentioned....that defining functions in the header file worked perfectly fine.